# What is the method can I use to send an event from native module to JS in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

According to React Native [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#sending-events-to-javascript), you can use `sendAppEventWithName` to send an event from native code to JS. But in my XCode, code suggestions tell me that this method is deprecated.

[image]

This [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/394) indicates that `sendDeviceEventWithName` should work but actually it's also deprecated.

What is the actual way to send an event to JS?

Comment: It is deprecated because you should subclass the `RCTEventEmitter` as of now. Unfortunately I can't tell you how but you can take a look in the repository history of the event dispatcher [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/d9737571c43d39af41d539de2dd12c2ceb5cda0e) under change #21

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Please take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8714) in which many people gave a lot of useful solutions.

---

I figured it out by reading its source code. Using the `RCTEventEmitter` class.

MyModule.h

```
#import "RCTEventEmitter.h"
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface MyModule : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

MyModule.m

```
@implementation MyModule

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (void)tellJS {
  [self sendEventWithName:@"sayHello" body:@"Hello"];
}

@end
```

So you can send an event called `sayHello` with data `Hello` to JavaScript by calling the `tellJS` method.

In JavaScript side, you have to use the `NativeModules` module to get this native module and wrap it in `NativeEventEmitter` class so that you can receive events.

```
import { NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter } from 'react-native'

const myModuleEvt = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.MyModule)
myModuleEvt.addListener('sayHello', (data) => console.log(data))
```

Comment: Note that you also have to have this method or you'll get an error: - (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents {
  return @[@"sayHello"];
}

Comment: I was used as u mentioned above and lost all the warnings but when i run my project it was crashed and saying like

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You must override the `supportedEvents` method of ImportingModulesSample'

Comment: I had the same issue I'm wondering if there is anyway to solved it Thread 1: signal SIGABRT and that happen in  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }